# jQuery Ajax - can't get a response

Tags: php, json, jquery

I am using this jQuery.ajax:

```
var url = "http://client.my_url.com/test_get_account_data.php";  
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(resultsData){
        alert("We're finally making the call.");
    },
    error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error:" + textStatus+ "," + errorThrown);
    } 
});
```

To hit this php script:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$myFile = "LogFile.log";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');

$accountJSON = array("id"=>"Level 3.accountName","type"=>"Level 3","name"=>"accountName","total"=>"1059.25","in"=>"8603.56","out"=>"7544.31");

$encodedResponse = json_encode($accountJSON);

fwrite($fh, "We're at the end of get_account_data with encodedResponse:\n");
fwrite($fh, $encodedResponse."\n");

echo $encodedResponse;
?>
```

But for some reason, I never get a success.  I've simplified this as much as I can imagine, but it still fails.  In the log, I have the output:

```
We're at the end of get_account_data with encodedResponse:<br/>
{"id":"Level 3.accountName", "type":"Level 3", "name":"accountName", "total":"1059.25", "in":"8603.56", "out":"7544.31"}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I would think this would be very easy... and maybe it is and I'm just doing something stupid.

Thanks

Comment: What does your browser's Javascript error console say?

Comment: Is your web page on the same domain as the PHP server?  Does your browser's error console or debug console report any javascript errors or security errors?

Comment: Tried `header("Content-Type: application/json");` ? You're not actually sending back plain text, are you?

Comment: Don't use the full url just use /dir/a/b/c/file.php check the logs if your using chrome

Comment: Javascript error console (firefox) has no errors.  There are warnings, but those appear to all be from jquery-ui css issues.
The net tab in firebug has this for the request header:
GET /test_get_account_data.php?_=1331419975860 HTTP/1.1
Host: client.sweepscoach.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8080/SCSalesDataReport/test/showReport?fromDate=today&toDate=today
Origin: http://localhost:8080

Comment: @Matijs That was what I tried first, I'll switch it back, but I anticipate the same result... Sure enough.  Same end result: Failed.

Comment: The response header is:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 10 Mar 2012 23:14:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.6 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.6 OpenSSL/0.9.7e-p1 DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 with Suhosin-Patch
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-Length: 111
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: @jfriend00 I have to run the php and the javascript on two different servers.  It sounds like I can't use JSON, but need to use JSONP, *but*, I can't use JSONP because some of my calls need to not be asynchronous. :/ I, in fact, am now *trying* to pass plain text, but I can't get that to work either.  *sigh*

Comment: @user384817 - I don't know where you get the idea that JSONP is not asynchronous.  If you dynamically insert the script tag (which most people do), it is asynchronous.  In JSONP, all data has to be in javascript form so you'd have to make your plain text a javascript string that can be passed to the JSONP callback function.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm afraid you'll have to dumb it down for me.  At http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ it states:
"By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active."  How do I get around this?

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, and why was this not a problem when I was using XML?  The dang thing worked fine when I was using XML...

Comment: I didn't realize you want synchronous (I misread your comment).  Dynamically generated JSONP calls will be asynchronous - there is no choice on that.  I don't know of any way of doing synchronous cross-domain javascript calls in a cross browser fashion.  You probably need to redesign to work with asynch calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to call `http://client.my_url.com` with AJAX GET request from `http://localhost:8080`

According to [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) of browsers you cannot send AJAX GET/POST requests to another domain. You need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for cross domain AJAX.

Comment: Can I make the transfer as plain text?  JSONP doesn't allow for non-asynchronous calls, and one of the calls I need to make needs that. I made the changes so that the response header has: "Content-Type: text/plain", and I added the "dataType: 'text'," parameter to the ajax call, but it seems to still not be returning anything. :(

Comment: It took me way longer than I would care to admit to get JSONP working, but it is now.  If anyone else ends up facing this problem, go here for more a walkthrough:
http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/
http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/