# how can i get html generated by a php script from another domain(cross-domain)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i am wondering how can get the HTML code which is generated by a cross-domain php script?

Normally if i'm on the same domain , i would use Ajax as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'user.php',
    data: 'user_id=user_id', //assuming user_id value was already set.
    success: function(html)
    {
        $('#info').empty().html(html);
    }  
});
```

But i am now working on a different domain than my server domain. Which means i use JSON to send data back and to my server php scripts.
However , i know that JSON only send data but not a complete HTML CODE(or am i missing out some point here?)

So , how can i get the html code generated by a cross-domain php script(server) to my web page(another domain).

Comment: use a php page that do `CURL` to external domain to get data from

Comment: what if that page is not php? and i want to use javascript to do it?

Comment: This answer is helpful I guess http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651105/778687

Answer (score 2):

using javascript you can do the same as if it was JSON, it's called JSONP the P is `with padding`.

Or you can call it JSON with callback:

// Request Page

```
myCallback("Some string or Object to parse to your site");
```

// Your Page

```
window["myCallback"] = function(string_or_object) {
    // Here you can do everything with the parsed data
}
```

Create a script-tag and include the request page. Make sure to define your callback before including the script-tag

or you can use jQuery's `ajax` method with `dataType` set to `jsonp`:

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "requst_page.php",
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    "success": function(string_or_object) {
        // Here you can do everything with the parsed data
    }
})
```

Look at http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

**EDIT TO COMMENT:**

JSON is right an object normally starts with braces `{}`.

Demo JSON:

```
{
    "myString": "myValue",
    "myOtherString": ["My", "Other", "Value", "This", "Is", "An", "Array"]
}
```

But using the same method as JSONP you can parse an string instead of the weird looking thing starting and ending with `{}`.

as `myCallback` in my example 1: `myCallback("HERE I PASS A STRING INSTEAD OF AN OBJECT")`. See the `""`. `"STRING GOES IN HERE"`

if it was JSON and taken usage of my DEMO JSON it would look like this:

```
myCallback({
    "myString": "myValue",
    "myOtherString": ["My", "Other", "Value", "This", "Is", "An", "Array"]
})
```

Comment: however , how can i get html contents from the php script with this? i thought JSON or JSONP width the { 'data' ,'data' } format?????\

Answer (score 1):

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'curl.php',
    data: 'user_id=user_id', //assuming user_id value was already set.
    success: function(html)
    {
        $('#info').empty().html(html);
    }  
});
```

**curl.php;**

```
function get_data($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$url= "http://www.example.com/user.php?user_id=".$user_id;
echo get_data($url);
```

Comment: I understand your technique. which the JS file sends a request to the curl.php which is on the same domain as it . then the curl.php will then go to the other domain which have my user information generated as HTML. However , what if i dont want to use curl.php with the ajax? what if i only want javascript to get the html from a different domain? is that possible?

Comment: i meant is curl.php must be on the same domain as the JS file which the ajax located.

Comment: @sm21guy yes must be in same domain

Comment: owh that's no good , as i want to know how to do this without having php scripts and the javascript on the same domain. Javascript --> get the html code from a php script on a different domain

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a proxy on your domain and use CURL to get the json from other domain. You then send request to this proxy.

Alternately you would need to set up the other domain to process request as jsonp in order to be able to access directly with ajax

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) or tell the website owner of the other site to add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score 0):

I also get same problem when access cross domain using ajax. Then I solve it by make the ajax call to same domain. Then on that php script I apply following code block. This will get the content from cros domain and out put the same to ajax call.

```
    $content = file_get_contents('http://crossdomain.com');
    echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through jsonp. Following is an example.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "example.com/respond.php",
   data: {id: id},
   dataType: "jsonp",
   jsonp : "callback",
   jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback"
});
```

respond.php

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/json"); 

if (isset($_GET['id'])) $rtnjsonobj->id = $_GET['id']; 
$rtnjsonobj->message = "This is the message from cross domain";


echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';    
?>
```